# SQL function that checks 3 tables

Tags: sql, function

I have the syntax of the function, but I am totally useless as to how i would put the conditions into code (SQL) so it would return an answer.

I have three tables,

```
T1.number varchar(max)
T1.date datetime
T1.ctps int

T2.number varchar(max)
T2.addedDate date
T2.RemovedDate date
T2.ctps int

T3.OType varchar(max)
T3.LNumber varchar(max)
```

and three variables,

```
@LNumber varchar(max), 
@OType varchar(max), 
@CDate datetime
```

I need the function to take the linenumber go into table 1 check if the number is in there if it is it then needs to grab the OType name and if it is LTD or PLC it then needs to check if the CPTS flag is set to 1 if it is then it needs to check the contractdate against T1.Date if contrcatdate before T1.Date then return "no" else if contractdate later than T1.Date then return "Yes"

here is my attemp no very good, a friend suggested using an if else staement in my function but no idea how to implement that either lol

any help would be appreciated

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TPS_Checker', N'FN') IS NOT NULL 

    DROP FUNCTION TPS_Checker ;

GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>    --@LineNumber = u.CLI, @OrganisationType = o.Name, @ContractDate = c.ContractDate 
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION TPS_Checker
(@LineNumber VARCHAR(MAX), @ContractDate DATETIME, @OrganisationType VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4)
AS


BEGIN

DECLARE @Answer varchar(4)

SELECT @Answer = CASE
                WHEN ((((((@LineNumber = [U].[CLI]) AND @OrganisationType  = 'PLC') OR @OrganisationType  = 'LTD') AND [U].[Date] IS NOT NULL) AND @ContractDate < [U].[Date]) AND [U].[CTPS] = 0) THEN 'No'
                WHEN ((((((@LineNumber = [U].[CLI]) AND @OrganisationType  = 'PLC') OR @OrganisationType  = 'LTD') AND [U].[Date] IS NOT NULL) AND @ContractDate < [U].[Date]) AND [U].[CTPS] = 1) THEN 'No' 
                WHEN ((((((@LineNumber = [U].[CLI]) AND @OrganisationType != 'PLC') OR @OrganisationType != 'LTD') AND [U].[Date] IS NOT NULL) AND @ContractDate < [U].[Date]) AND [U].[CTPS] = 0) THEN 'No'
                WHEN ((((((@LineNumber = [U].[CLI]) AND @OrganisationType != 'PLC') OR @OrganisationType != 'LTD') AND [U].[Date] IS NOT NULL) AND @ContractDate < [U].[Date]) AND [U].[CTPS] = 1) THEN 'No'
                WHEN ((((((@LineNumber = [U].[CLI]) AND @OrganisationType  = 'PLC') OR @OrganisationType  = 'LTD') AND [U].[Date] IS NOT NULL) AND @ContractDate > [U].[Date]) AND [U].[CTPS] = 0) THEN 'No'
                WHEN ((((((@LineNumber = [U].[CLI]) AND @OrganisationType != 'PLC') OR @OrganisationType != 'LTD') AND [U].[Date] IS NOT NULL) AND @ContractDate > [U].[Date]) AND [U].[CTPS] = 1) THEN 'Yes'
                WHEN ((((((@LineNumber = [U].[CLI]) AND @OrganisationType != 'PLC') OR @OrganisationType != 'LTD') AND [U].[Date] IS NOT NULL) AND @ContractDate > [U].[Date]) AND [U].[CTPS] = 0) THEN 'Yes'
                END


FROM [Contract] c
INNER JOIN [Account] a
        ON [c].[AccountFK] = [a].[AccountID]
INNER JOIN [Profile] p
        ON [p].[ProfileID] = [a].[ProfileFK]
INNER JOIN [Line] l
        ON [l].[ContractFK] = [ContractID]
LEFT JOIN [Deal] d
        ON [c].[ContractID] = [d].[ContractFK]
INNER JOIN    (      SELECT BranchTypeFK, BranchID, Name   
                            FROM [Branch] b
                        )b
        ON [d].[BranchFK] = [b].[BranchID]
        AND BranchTypeFK IN (1,2,4)
INNER JOIN [OrganisationType] o
        ON [p].[OrganisationTypeFK]  = [o].[OrganisationTypeID] 
LEFT JOIN  [Lookup] U
        ON U.CLI  = l.LineNumber
LEFT JOIN History H
        ON h.CLI  = l.LineNumber

return @answer

    -- Return the result of the function


RETURN @Answer
END

    select top 100 [CORPORATE\HargreavesD].[TPS_Checker1](u.CLI ,c.ContractDate,o.Name) Answer 
FROM [Contract] c
INNER JOIN [Account] a
        ON [c].[AccountFK] = [a].[AccountID]
INNER JOIN [Profile] p
        ON [p].[ProfileID] = [a].[ProfileFK]
INNER JOIN [Line] l
        ON [l].[ContractFK] = [ContractID]
LEFT JOIN [Deal] d
        ON [c].[ContractID] = [d].[ContractFK]
INNER JOIN    (      SELECT BranchTypeFK, BranchID, Name   
                            FROM [Branch] b
                        )b
        ON [d].[BranchFK] = [b].[BranchID]
        AND BranchTypeFK IN (1,2,4)
INNER JOIN [OrganisationType] o
        ON [p].[OrganisationTypeFK]  = [o].[OrganisationTypeID] 
LEFT JOIN  [Lookup] U
        ON U.CLI  = l.LineNumber
LEFT JOIN History H
        ON h.CLI  = l.LineNumber
```

THIS  IS MY FIRST ATTEMPT BUT NOT IN A FUNCTION

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '01/04/2013'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '30/04/2013'

SELECT  ContractID
        ,LineNumber
        ,ContractDate
        ,[Date]
        ,o.Name
        ,u.[File]
        ,DateAdded
        ,DateRemoved
        ,u.CTPS
        ,B.Name [Branch Name]

        END
INTO [TPS]
FROM [Contract] c
INNER JOIN [Account] a
    ON [c].[AccountFK] = [a].[AccountID]
INNER JOIN [Profile] p
    ON [p].[ProfileID] = [a].[ProfileFK]
INNER JOIN [Line] l
    ON [l].[ContractFK] = [ContractID]
LEFT JOIN [Deal] d
    ON [c].[ContractID] = [d].[ContractFK]
INNER JOIN  (   SELECT BranchTypeFK, BranchID, Name   
                FROM [Branch] b
            )b
    ON [d].[BranchFK] = [b].[BranchID]
    AND BranchTypeFK IN (1,2,4)
INNER JOIN [OrganisationType] o
    ON [p].[OrganisationTypeFK]  = [o].[OrganisationTypeID] 
LEFT JOIN   (
            SELECT [CLI], [Date] [lDate], [Date], [CTPS], [File] = 'Lookup'  
            FROM [Lookup] tl
            )u
    ON u.CLI  = l.LineNumber
LEFT JOIN   (
            SELECT [CLI], [DateAdded], [DateRemoved], [CTPS], [File] = 'History'  
            FROM History h
            )h
    ON h.CLI  = l.LineNumber 
WHERE ContractDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

SELECT  *
        ,[OnTPS] =  CASE
                    WHEN ([Date] IS NOT NULL AND [ContractDate] < [Date]) THEN 'No'
                    WHEN ([Date] IS NOT NULL AND [ContractDate] > [Date]) THEN 'Yes' 

                    WHEN ([Date] IS NULL AND [ContractDate] BETWEEN [DateAdded] AND [DateRemoved]) THEN 'Yes'
                    WHEN ([Date] IS NULL AND [ContractDate] NOT BETWEEN [DateAdded] AND [DateRemoved]) THEN 'No'

                    WHEN ([Date] IS NULL AND [ContractDate] BETWEEN [DateAdded] AND [DateRemoved] AND [Name] = 'PLC' OR [Name] = 'LTD' AND CTPS = 1) THEN 'Yes'
                    WHEN ([Date] IS NULL AND [ContractDate] BETWEEN [DateAdded] AND [DateRemoved] AND [Name] = 'PLC' OR [Name] = 'LTD' AND CTPS = 0) THEN 'No'

                    WHEN ([Date] IS NOT NULL AND [ContractDate] > [Date] AND [Name] = 'PLC' OR [Name] = 'LTD' AND CTPS = 1) THEN 'Yes'
                    WHEN ([Date] IS NOT NULL AND [ContractDate] > [Date] AND [Name] = 'PLC' OR [Name] = 'LTD' AND CTPS = 0) THEN 'No'
                    END
FROM [Temp].[dbo].[TPS] t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main query can be simplified slightly, but still giving the same result (I think - without test data it's tricky to tell):

```
    SELECT @Answer = CASE
            WHEN (@OrganisationType  = 'PLC' OR @OrganisationType  = 'LTD') AND @ContractDate < [U].[Date] AND [U].[CTPS] = 0 THEN 'No'
            WHEN (@OrganisationType  = 'PLC' OR @OrganisationType  = 'LTD') AND @ContractDate < [U].[Date] AND [U].[CTPS] = 1 THEN 'No' 
            WHEN (@OrganisationType != 'PLC' OR @OrganisationType != 'LTD') AND @ContractDate < [U].[Date] AND [U].[CTPS] = 0 THEN 'No'
            WHEN (@OrganisationType != 'PLC' OR @OrganisationType != 'LTD') AND @ContractDate < [U].[Date] AND [U].[CTPS] = 1 THEN 'No'
            WHEN (@OrganisationType  = 'PLC' OR @OrganisationType  = 'LTD') AND @ContractDate > [U].[Date] AND [U].[CTPS] = 0 THEN 'No'
            WHEN (@OrganisationType != 'PLC' OR @OrganisationType != 'LTD') AND @ContractDate > [U].[Date] AND [U].[CTPS] = 1 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN (@OrganisationType != 'PLC' OR @OrganisationType != 'LTD') AND @ContractDate > [U].[Date] AND [U].[CTPS] = 0 THEN 'Yes'
        END
    FROM [Contract] c
        INNER JOIN [Account] a ON [c].[AccountFK] = [a].[AccountID]
            INNER JOIN [Profile] p ON [p].[ProfileID] = [a].[ProfileFK]
                INNER JOIN [OrganisationType] o ON [p].[OrganisationTypeFK] = [o].[OrganisationTypeID] 
        INNER JOIN [Line] l ON [l].[ContractFK] = [c].[ContractID]
            INNER JOIN [Lookup] U ON U.CLI  = l.LineNumber
        LEFT JOIN [Deal] d ON [c].[ContractID] = [d].[ContractFK]
            INNER JOIN  [Branch] b ON [d].[BranchFK] = [b].[BranchID] AND BranchTypeFK IN (1,2,4)
    WHERE [U].[CLI] = @LineNumber
      AND [U].[Date] IS NOT NULL
```

You're also returning `@Answer` twice at the bottom of your function, and there are situations in which `@Answer` may still be `NULL`; that may be deliberate. Other than that, if it meets your business requirements and performs at an acceptable speed then there's no real driver for further rewrites of this function.

Comment: Why don't you simplify your case statement to have two WHENs (for the two YESs) and an ELSE for all the NOs?

Comment: I could, good idea - but there may be cases in which none of the conditions are true and so `@answer` should return NULL. OP - should 'No' be returned instead of a NULL value if neither of the 'Yes' conditions match?

Comment: no your answer just returns NULL for all rows ow would i convert into if else maybe that would work better ?

Comment: yes cases where the number is not held within the check table so should return null for that row

Comment: @LoveToys I've altered the JOINs slightly, can you take another look? I don't think having an if ... else would actually help here, as you'd simply end up with multiple queries instead of just one single one - a CASE here does seem to be the best way.

Comment: @Wragg ill check the joins now had to change names of them as didnt want to give out proper table names also you have cut off the last joins I know they are not needed for this part of the query but they are for the next part because if the number is not in the first table it then has to check the history table to see if the number is in there and the format of that table is slightly different to the first check table instead of having a date it has a date added and a date removed

Comment: @LoveToys Thanks for the clarification, I didn't realise that your CASE would be expanded further so they'd be required further down the line.

Comment: yes the joins seem to work but when i run the function with this select statement it returns nothing but column header?

Comment: it wont let me put in the rest of the select statment to use the function

Comment: its the same joins as you put in the answer earlier and sorry i didnt explain completely i just thought i might be able to do the rest from the help i get from this part of the question

Comment: If you're only getting the column header and no rows, then it's not the function at fault - you're not actually passing any rows to the function in the first place, so the JOIN you're using to test with is incorrect. If the function were not working you would at least be given a column of NULL values.

Comment: select top 100 [CORPORATE\HargreavesD].[TPS_Checker1](u.CLI ,c.ContractDate,o.Name) Answer

Comment: thats the statement im using to pass in the rows of data held within the table
then the from statement you built in your answer

Comment: If you are getting no rows at all returned, then you are not even calling the function in the first place. Your problem therefore is related to the structure and data within your tables and thus not something anyone on StackOverflow can help with.

Comment: NO THE DATA IS FINE I HAVE HAD IT WORKING UP TO A POINT

Comment: I HAVE ADDED CODE TO ORIGINAL QUESTION WHICH I CREATED FIRST THEN WAS ASKED TO CREATE FUNCTION THAT DOES SAME THING THIS STORED PROCEDURE THAT I HAVE BUILT NEARLY WORKS JUST NEEDS SOME WORK ON THE COMPARISON RULES. SO NEED THIS TRANSLATING INTO A FUNCTION

Comment: You said you were getting 'nothing but the header'. That implies no rows, not a column of NULLs. You also already have a function, not a stored procedure. I'll leave this question for someone else to pick up instead, as they may be more willing to discuss this with you; I hope your day is as pleasant as you have been.

Comment: i was getting a column of nulls before i changed the joins which you created now only getting the header of the column and the last post i put up is not a function its just a query i was going to turn into a stored procedure, thanks for your help

under THIS IS MY FIRST ATTEMPT

Comment: @Adrian Wragg 
i used your joins and case statement with a little tweek and it seems to be working thank you so much Adrian your a superstar